# subset-sum algorithm and recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, subset

After some research, below is a modified version of the subset_sum recursion I found on SO. The modified version attempts to not only return the exact sum if there is one, but also returns the closest set of integers if an exact sum cannot be found. Furthermore, there is a list size requirement that determines how many numbers must be added up to determine the final sum

```
def findFourPlus(itemCount, seq, goal):
    goalDifference = float("inf")
    closestPartial = []
    subset_sum(itemCount, seq, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial=[])
    print(closestPartial)

def subset_sum(itemCount, seq, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial):
s = sum(partial)

# check if the partial sum is equals to target
if(len(partial) == itemCount):
    if s == goal:
            print(partial)
    else:
        if( abs(goal - s) < goalDifference):
            goalDifference = abs(goal - s)
            closestPartial = partial        

for i in range(len(seq)):
    n = seq[i]
    remaining = seq[i+1:]
    subset_sum(itemCount, remaining, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial + [n])
```

The problem I am facing right now is that **closesetPartial** will always be an empty list, because each call of **subset_sum()** will refresh **cloestPartial** back to an empty list. I tried to move **goalDifference** and **cloestPartial** initialization outside of subset_sum function, but I am return with **local variable 'goalDifference' referenced before assignment** error.

What can I do to both preserve the recursive algorithm while keeping track of the closest-sum so far? and is there a better way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `closestPartial` and `goalDifference` outside of the call to `subset_sum` and pass them in as parameters.  Either maintain a single `closestPartial` that is passed by reference to every `subset_sum` call, or else pass a copy of `closestPartial` to each `subset_sum` call - the former will likely be more efficient, while the latter will be easier to implement / reason about because it will be free of side-effects.

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestions. I've edited the algorithm above, but now it's returning " TypeError: subset_sum() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'closestPartial' and 'partial' ", which I don't understand since I already defined closestPartial and partial is a default argument

Comment: Just kidding, it appears I forgot about the bottom subset_sum recursive call. The above algorithm still only returns an empty closestpartial list. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3277633 I think what's happening is that you're changing the `closestPartial` reference to point to the `partial` reference, but the outer function doesn't see this - it's still got a reference to the original `closestPartial`, not to the updated reference.  You can either copy `partial` element-by-element into `closestPartial`, or else you can wrap `closestPartial` and pass around the wrapper, e.g. `struct Wrapper { closestPartial [] }` - then when you update the reference inside the wrapper the outer function will see the updated reference.

Comment: I've tried setting cloestPartial = list(partial) or closestPartial = copy.copy(partial), but neither of them works. I am wondering if the logic behind my call is even correct?